# If statement in JadeJS

Tags: node.js, if-statement, mongoose, pug, equality

I am having a little problem using Jade JS that doesn't let me finish my app.
I have a Mongo DB with questions, answers, and comments.
I want to display comments under each answer, so I use a FOR loop to compare the answer ID with the 'answer_id' of each comment.

So it would be like this:

```
for answer in answers
    br
    a #{answer.user}
    span #{answer.date.toLocaleDateString()} (#{answer.date.getHours()}:#{answer.date.getMinutes()})
    br
    pre #{answer.text}
    textarea(id='#{answer._id}',class='comm',placeholder='Comment this answer')
    span
        a.btn(href='javascript:post("#{answer._id}")') Send
    br
    br
        p asdadsdadas
    for comment in comments
        if comment
            if ('#{comment.answer_id}' == '#{answer._id}')
                p '#{answer._id}'
                p '#{comment.answer_id}'
    hr
```

The problem is that for Jade this is NOT equal, but if I change it to != to check the '#{answer._id}' and '#{comment.answer_id}' it shows me exactly the same...
So I don't know what's going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
- if (comment.answer_id == answer._id)
```

instead of

```
if ('#{comment.answer_id}' == '#{answer._id}')
```